# BottomNavigation View back button on pressed change state

Tags: android, android-fragments

So let me try to explain this: I have a Bottom navigation view with three buttons, each one when pressed will load a fragment. However, when pressing the back button, i have programmed the back stack to go back to the fragment it was previously. However, the colour of the navigation button does not change after the back button is changed. I know this has something to do with the state checked thing but i do not know how to implement it on my codes. Here are the codes

This is the menu page, it sets the bottomnavigation view only in which the main_frame is where the fragments are going to be:

```
public class menuPage extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView mainNav;
FrameLayout mainFrame;

private MoviesFragment moviesFragment;
private HomeFragment homeFragment;
private ProfileFragment profileFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_page);


    mainFrame= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    mainNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

    moviesFragment= new MoviesFragment ();
    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment ();

    removeFragment(homeFragment);

    mainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_movies :
                    setFragment(moviesFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_home :
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    setFragment(profileFragment);
                    return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detail");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
private void removeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Here is the codes for the Home Fragment, Movies Fragment and Profile Fragment respectively. You can ignore the codes written inside cos i know it correctly goes to another activity when launched and that has nothing to do with this issue

Home Fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

}

Movies Fragment

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listofmovies;
ArrayList<String> genres;
ArrayAdapter<String> listview;


NowShowing nowShowing;
ComingSoon comingsoon;

@Override//inflate this
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    listofmovies = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.movielist);
    genres = new ArrayList<String>();
    listview = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, genres);
    listofmovies.setAdapter(listview);

    //The types of options
    genres.add("Now Showing");
    genres.add("Coming Soon");
    genres.add("July");
    genres.add("June");


    nowShowing = new NowShowing();
    comingsoon = new ComingSoon();

    listofmovies.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent nextPage = new Intent(view.getContext(), NowShowing.class);
                startActivityForResult(nextPage,0);
            }
            if (position == 1){
                Intent nextPage = new Intent(view.getContext(),ComingSoon.class);
                startActivityForResult(nextPage,1);
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Profile Fragment

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
ListView management;
ArrayList<String> mis;
ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container, false );
    management= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.management);
    mis= new ArrayList<String>();
    Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mis);
    management.setAdapter(Adapter);
    //add management settings
    mis.add("Settings");
    mis.add("Favourites");
    mis.add("Log Out");

    userprofilefragment userprofilefragment = new userprofilefragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.profilelayout, userprofilefragment, userprofilefragment.getTag())
            .commit();
    return view;
}
```

Help is much appreciated. The context is that I'm just making a simple movie app for school assignment and i am still kinda beginner at Java..
Thanks